# Why ohm started his derivation from $V$ is directly propotional to $I$ but In his statment he says $I$ is directly propotional to $V$?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Why ohm started his derivation from $V$ is directly propotional to $I$ but in his statement he says I is directly proportional to V?

Comment: What statement is that?

Comment: Statement:- if physical condition of conductor remains constant the current flowing in the conductor is directly propotional to the potential diffrence across its end...

Comment: It's equivalent, if $V=kI$ then $I=(k^{-1})V$.

Comment: But how you can say that it is equivalent..becoz formula of resistance varies ....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of mathematics, and it is not clear what you are asking about physics.

Comment: @anuj I believe that by "*formula of resistance varies*" you mean that the proportionality constant varies. And that is true. But that doesn't change the fact that the two parameters are proportional in both cases - both cases show direct proportionality just with different proportionality constants.

Comment: As a matter of good scientific practice, Ohm was almost certainly varying the voltage (by changing the number of plates in a stack battery of some kind) and measuring the current, so the proper formulation of the resulting data is $I = I(V)$ not $V = V(I)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same thing. $V$ being proportional to $I$  means that $I$ is proportional to $V$.

But the proportionality constants are different, so the law might have been set up in the simplest possible way as
$$V=RI$$
instead of 
$$I=\frac{1}{R}V$$

Direct proportionality is seen in both cases, $V\propto I$ and $I\propto V$, just with different proportionality constants (which naturally are just each other's inverses, $R$ and $1/R$).